# How to make Asp.net MVC 3 tier project solution using Entity Framework (database-first)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I didn't find any good answers regarding of 3 tier architecture using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework (database-first).

I know in UI layer will be an ASP.NET MVC project.

- Where will be Entity Framework?
- What will be in DA layer?
- What will be in BL layer?

Comment: Our of curiosity, what prevents you from using ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: @abatishchev ... I m using mvc5 but i want to know how to implement 3 tier architecture using mvc framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize your MVC project architecture separating your DAL, BL and Presentation logic creating three different projects, naming each of them, for example, with suffix DAL, BL and Web. The first two projects will be class libraries, the Web will be an mvc application.

EntityFramework goes obviusly in the DAL project. Then, all your domain model logic will goes in the BL project.

Finally, your Web/Presentation project will implements all controllers, that invoke domain services in the BL and manage views through view models components and dto objects to/from BL (your Model objects).

Comment: Covino thanks for replying .... so the Add,Update, Delete and my custom methods will be in BAL correct?

Comment: Yes. You may implement your repository classes in the DAL project where you put in your crud logic

Comment: If custom methods implement specific core business logic, then they go in BL and they have to be separated from repositories in the DAL

Comment: You are welcome, thank you (y)

Comment: Brother , one more confusion. In DAL Layer Entity framework will generate all the classes (Example Customer,Project etc). So in business Layer , do i have to copy those classes in BAL ? . Or only write Methods (create Customer, Get Customer) and used those BAL methods in UI layer?

Comment: Exactly... In the business layer you have implement all of those objects that will have to manage operations such CreateNewCustomer but focusing on applying all business rules about this process and separating these rules management and their application from your DAL, into which you will manage simply CRUD basic operation through Entity Framework. (...)

Comment: (...)  Obviusly, when you create a new customer, after you have applied all validation logic, and other eventual business logic, you will have to pass at your DAL objects (better if it is an object that apply repository pattern: CustomerRepository) your entity framework object Customer to store.

Comment: thanks again :) . So i have created solution with 3 projects (UI i.e. MVC , DAL and BLL) .  In DAL i created Entity Framework and also created Generic Repositery class in which i wrote CRUD methods. Now in BLL i again added a class example UserProfileData.cs , inside this class i created object of Generic Repositery Class ( GenericRepository<UserProfile> objDb = new GenericRepository<UserProfile>();  )  and  created methods again by using objDb methods.  Now in MVC project i will access BLL and use its methods....... is this correct ?

Comment: Yes it is correct. compliments

Comment: thank you for your precious time :)

Comment: Sir One more Question. In BLL i return Entities of DAL (EF class). So in UI i have to add DAL reference which is incorrect. What will be the solution?. eg in BLL there is method public UserProfileDAL getAll(). If i use this method in UI it is returning EF Entity (UserProfileDAL). What should i return from BLL?

Comment: :).. You have define your Model objects.. Simple dto objects that each BL method exchange in input/output with the UI

Comment: Thanks alot sir i learned new things. I added a sparate project BOL (Business object layer) and here i added EF Dbcontext generator which pointed towards my .edmx file inside DAL. I removed .tt files from DAL edmx. Now i have all entities in BOL which i added reference in UI and BLL layer for coding.